# TWELITE 2525Aの論理デバイスIDにOTA設定で連番を割り当てる方法

Tags: センサー, シリアル通信

表題の作業について、本質問の**やりたいこと**のように省力化や自動化する方法はあるのでしょうか。

加速度センサー無線タグのTWELITE 2525Aを数十個購入して、端末ごとに`論理デバイスID`を1,2,3...と連番で割り当てる作業が発生しました。
MONOSTICKを使ったOTAで下記の手順で連番を振る作業を行います。

1. Tera Termなどのターミナルソフトを起動する
2. Enterキーを押して`インタラクティブモード`相当の状態にする
3. 連番以外の設定を変更する
4. `i`→`連番`→`Enter`を入力して`論理デバイスID`を変更する
5. `S`を押して設定を保存する
6. 未設定のTWELITE 2525AをMONOSTICKに近づけて通電する
7. `Success`が表示されることを確認する

実際の繰り返し作業は4～7だけで、キーボードマクロを使って連番入力を省力化すれば大変な作業ではないのですが、もしも今後この作業が何度も発生することになったなら更に省力化できないかと別の設定方法を調べています。

**やりたいこと**

下記のような対策ができればベストなのですが、同様の作業で対策を取られている方がいましたらご教示願います。

- ターミナルソフトで対話的に`論理デバイスID`を書き換えるのではなく、ソフトやコマンドで非対話に設定を書き換える
- TWELITE 2525AをMONOSTICKに近づけて通電するのではなく、既に通電済みのTWELITE 2525Aに対して設定を書き換える

`論理デバイスID`ではなく`子機SID`を使う対策もありますが、今回は接続するDBのIDキーが数値型であり、子機の故障時に同一のIDを振って代替機とする運用も想定しているため論理デバイスIDを利用します。